# Unity with android and Vuforia

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, vuforia, vuforia-cloud-recognition

Is it necessary to use unity with Android studio and Vuforia when developing android ? I'm using Vuforia only to recognize images via camera and perform activity. Also can I use google cloud instead of vuforia-cloud to store images

Answer (score 0):

You can just use Unity and develop your app in unity editor without the need to Android Studio.

[Here is a tutorial to use Vuforia Object Recognition in Unity](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/How-To-Use-Object-Recognition-in-Unity.html)

You Can Also use prepared Assets from Unity's Asset store like [this one](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/templates/multi-platform-image-detection-plugin-20410).

Comment: Thanks for responding, the reason why I don't want to use Unity is -> I'm not familiar with unity and -> I have an already existing android application where I want to update this new module of image recognition. So is how can I implement image recognition functionality in Android Studio using Vuforia only not Unity ?